# Negative consequences to regularly re-certifying with LetsEncrypt?

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a Docker container that does the following things in succession:

- Start an NGINX server with just HTTP on port 80
- Run Certbot's certonly command to generate certificates
- Restart the NGINX server with new config to also do HTTPS on 443

This is very convenient because if we move servers/even domains, I know that all I have to do is startup and we will be good to go. The unfortunate result though is that when I recreate the container I will go through the certification process over again for the same domain. This works currently, but I am wondering if there are negative consequences to this approach. Does LetsEncrypt put any stipulations or limitations on going through the certification process for the same domain? Are there other concerns to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

The only negative consequence I can think of (and you already had a clue about it) is hitting the [let's encrypt rate limit](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) in case your container re-spawns too quickly for example.

You should read that page carefully and see if this can be a problem in your case (there are several limits for different interactions with the service). Don't forget there is a staging environment your can use while testing deploys so that you don't hit the limits when your finally get to production.

I personally have some automated services that use automatic let's encrypt certificate generation/renewal and I've never hit those limits.

Answer (score 0):

While LetsEncrypt does have rate limits, the certbot can be configured to only renew certificates that are nearing expiry. To use this functionality, you'll want to store your certificates in a persistent location that gets mounted into the container as a volume.

The [install documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html) describes the volume recommendations:

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot \
            -v "/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" \
            -v "/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" \
            certbot/certbot certonly
```

And the [command line options](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-certs) includes a `--keep` flag:

> ```
>   --keep-until-expiring, --keep, --reinstall
>                         If the requested certificate matches an existing
>                         certificate, always keep the existing one until it is
>                         due for renewal (for the 'run' subcommand this means
>                         reinstall the existing certificate). (default: Ask)
> ```

Comment: Could you use the keep flag without the volume mounts? So you keep the same set of credentials but just go through the maybe unnecessary roundtrips of sending the request to letsencrypt to find that out

Comment: @pasquers where would the previously retrieved certificates be stored?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what they mean by 'matches an existing certificate'. I thought that meant matches an existing certificate on letsencrypt's end. Does it mean it matches one currently in /etc/letsencrypt?

Comment: @pasquers existing certificate would be a local file. I highly doubt LetsEncrypt is storing your private keys on their server to give back out to you.